# Trigger Doctrine lifecycle events in my code

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

**Question**: how to **trigger** Doctrine lifecycle events in my code, having the entity data available?

## Details

- I have an active listener on the Doctrine `postPersist` and `postUpdate` events.
- I cannot modify / override this listener.
- In some places in my code, for performance reasons, I use DBAL to save data instead of ORM methods.
- I'd like to stick to the same event system.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have access to the entity manager then:

```
$eventManager = $entityManager->getEventManager();
```

After that you can build and dispatch events per the documentation.

I checked to see if there is a predefined service but did not see one.  But you probably define one as a factory and inject it as needed.

Hope this is what you are asking for.

Comment: You sent me on the right way and because of this I accepted your answer. I will now add another answer with some more sample code. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Extending @Cerad answer, here's a very basic sample code to achieve the result (trigger a Doctrine LifeCycle event). This sample assumes we're in a **Symfony** controller:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
// ...
$user = new AppBundle\Entity\User();
// ... do something with the user
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$eventManager = $entityManager->getEventManager();
$eventArgs = new LifecycleEventArgs($user, $entityManager);
$eventManager->dispatchEvent(\Doctrine\ORM\Events::postPersist, $eventArgs);
```